# How can i parse data from json file to fl_chart in flutter?

Tags: flutter, linechart, fl-chart

I am new to flutter and i am trying to use fl_chart as a chart to my application. I am using the following Dummy code snippet which is running successfully but i want to parse data from local json from asset folder and use xvalue & yvalue from json to FlSpot.

```
LineChartBarData(
              spots: [
                FlSpot(0,0),
                FlSpot(1, 1),
                FlSpot(2, 3),
                FlSpot(3, 3),
                FlSpot(4, 5),
                FlSpot(4, 4)
              ],
```

Comment: please post your full json string. thanks.

Comment: child: FutureBuilder(
          future: DefaultAssetBundle.of(context)
              .loadString('assets/stock_market_data.json'),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            var myData = jsonDecode(snapshot.data.toSstring());

Comment: sorry, I mean content of assets/stock_market_data.json. could you post full string? thanks

Comment: That is really huge up to 50k+  ... i am giving here first two part of that json data

{"date": "2020-08-10", "trade_code": "1JANATAMF", "high": "4.3", "low": "4.1", "open": "4.2", "close": "4.1", "volume": "2,285,416"}, {"date": "2020-08-09", "trade_code": "1JANATAMF", "high": "4.3", "low": "4.1", "open": "4.1", "close": "4.2", "volume": "1,292,933"},